# Make NuGet WebApi.HelpPage package go away

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

I did this in the NuGet console to try out the Web Api help package:
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage

Now everytime I create a MVC Web Api project I get Areas\HelpPage.

I tried:

```
PM> Uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage
Skipping 'Areas\HelpPage\Views\_ViewStart.cshtml' because it was modified.
Skipping 'Areas\HelpPage\Views\_ViewStart.cshtml' because it was modified.
Skipping 'Areas\HelpPage\Views\_ViewStart.cshtml' because it was modified.
Skipping 'Areas\HelpPage\Views\_ViewStart.cshtml' because it was modified.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage 4.0.0' from MvcApplication16.
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage 4.0.0'.

PM>
```

I decided not to use the HelpPage pacakge.

How can I make that HelpPage and its Area go away and not be in every project I create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually a feature in VS2012.2 update (or webtools 2012.2 release).  It's not due to that you installed that package once or not.  If you don't like it, you have 2 options:
1. remove the package everytime you after creating a new webapi project
2. Create a customized webapi template (search on asp.net on how to do that) that only installs the packages that you'd like

Comment: I missed that it was permanent. I created a Web Api project a couple of weeks ago and had just been working on it and there was no HelpPage at that time. I did not realize this was part of the update. Thanks.